# How does this recipe take ten days?

Tags: yeast, boiling

[This recipe](https://msmarmitelover.com/2011/04/how-to-make-your-own-marmite.html) for homemade Marmite says,"The entire process takes about ten days." How can that be? From what I see here I can't see it taking longer than four days. Or does that apply only to industrial-scale Marmite-making?

Comment: maybe it's a typo or missing step ? have you tried asking the author of the recipe ?

Comment: How do you "boil at 90C" without changing elevation?  Doesn't seem to be a well-written recipe.

Comment: @moscafj I wondered that too; I was planning just to boil at 100C, TBH.

Comment: @moscafj - she says in the recipe that factories use a special machine to boil at 90 c, or you could climb a mountain 10000 feet high. So I'd simmer at 90, personally. The recipe seems clear to me, but I agree with op that it wouldn't take 10 days. I'd think 6 or 7 though. It takes a long time for a thick liquid to filter through coffee paper. And it will also take an extra day or two to simmer the vegetables, strain, and reduce.

Comment: Look, any recipe can take 10 days if you spend enough of it procrastinating.